How to set the cookies of redirect website using react js?
This some code i was trying to set cookies of url using react when it redirect to that url.
 // Function to set cookies
    const setCookies = () => {
        // Parse JSON string into a JavaScript object
        const cookies = JSON.parse(jsonString);

        // Redirect to another domain with cookies as URL parameters
        redirectToAnotherDomain(cookies);
    };

    const redirectToAnotherDomain = (cookies) => {
        // Construct URL with cookies as parameters
        let url = 'http://192.168.56.3/user/student2/notebooks/OPENMP.ipynb?';
        cookies.forEach(cookie => {
            url += `${cookie.name}=${cookie.value}&`;
        });
        // Redirect to the constructed URL
        window.location.href = url;
    };

like, When the react redirect to this url =>
let url = 'http://192.168.56.3/user/student2/notebooks/OPENMP.ipynb?';
i want to set cookies of this url.
I want to solve this problem of setting cookies of url react redirect to, is there any way i can achieve it ?
